# Which account name has the most ordered items? SQLDev

Tags: sql, oracle

Which account name has the MOST ordered items?

Here is my code:

```
select account_name, count(ordered_item) 
  from oe_order_lines_all ool, cust_accounts_all hca, oe_order_headers_all ooh
  where to_date(ooh.creation_date) > '2015-10-01' and to_date(ooh.creation_date) < '2015-11-01'
  and ooh.flow_status_code <> 'CANCELLED'
  and ooh.sys_document_ref = ool.sys_document_ref
  and hca.cust_account_id=ooh.org_id
  group by hca.account_name, ool.ordered_item
  order by ool.ordered_item DESC
```

When I run this it returns Walmart Store: 2 items, Walmart Store: 4 Items instead of just saying Walmart ordered this many items. If I use distinct then it returns an error. I am unsure how to get the distinct account name with the amount ordered during October. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: I now know I should use the ROW_NUMBER and partition for this issue. But I cannot get the syntax right.

Comment: `to_date(ooh.creation_date) > '2015-10-01'`? There's so much wrong with this for such a short piece of code! What's the datatype of ooh.creation_date? If it's a date, why're you converting it to a date? Also, why are you using to_date without a corresponding date format? If you just want to remove the time part from the column (well, reset it to midnight), generally you'd use `trunc()`. Also, if you're comparing a date to a literal value, you should make sure that the value is also a date. This could probably be rewritten as `ooh.creation_date > to_date('2015-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Comment: If ooh.creation_date is a varchar2 column (or a number column) - ugh! - then you'd need to do: `to_date(ooh.creation_date, '<format mask>') > to_date('2015-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`. (Obviously, however you fix this predicate, you would also need to apply to the other ooh.creation_date comparison predicate!)

Comment: I have ran many codes using to_date and it works fine. The reason I use to_date is because there is a time stamp on the date. You are correct, I can (and probably should) use trunc(ooh.creation_date) between  '2015-10-01' and '2015-10-31'.  I was recently told to use to_date instead of trunc for reasons unknown. Ill do my research on the difference.

Comment: Using to_date on something that is already in date format actually forces an implicit conversion back into a string before reconverting it back into a date. E.g. `to_date(sysdate)` => `to_date(to_char(sysdate, '<nls_date_format>'), '<nls_date_format>)` If you haven't had an issue with it so far, it's pure luck, although by excluding the format mask from the to_date, you have avoided the issue where the implicit format mask could be different. However, if your nls_date_format parameter is set to something like 'dd-MON-rr' you could see funky things happening with the year. Why risk it?

Comment: And please, please, PLEASE, always explicitly convert your date-as-strings into dates when doing date comparisons by using to_date('<date-as-string>', '<format mask of date-string>'). Give the optimizer a fighting chance of getting it right by being explicit. Also, in your case, you don't need to trunc() the ooh.creation_date column, since you're comparing it to a range; 10/10/2015 10:00 is still greater than or equal to 01/10/2015 00:00 and before 01/11/2015, as is 10/10/2015 00:00. The time portion is not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `ROW_NUMBER` within your query:

```
SELECT * FROM (

      select account_name, count(ordered_item), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_name, ordered_item ORDER BY count(ordered_item) DESC) Row
      from oe_order_lines_all ool, cust_accounts_all hca, oe_order_headers_all ooh
      where to_date(ooh.creation_date) > '2015-10-01' and to_date(ooh.creation_date) < '2015-11-01'
      and ooh.flow_status_code <> 'CANCELLED'
      and ooh.sys_document_ref = ool.sys_document_ref
      and hca.cust_account_id=ooh.org_id
      group by hca.account_name, ool.ordered_item
      order by ool.ordered_item DESC

)data
where Row = 1
```

Just to describe what's happening here:

ROW_NUMBER() is a function within SQL that allows you "rank" each row within a unique partition of the table. (A partition being the collection of rows within a table that all hold the same value for a particular column. In our example below there are two partitions based on the account_name column, one for `ASDA` and one for `TESCO`).

The `OVER (PARTITION BY...` clause splits the rows by the specified expression (column), e.g. here we split the rows by account_name.

```
+---------+--------------+------------+
| account | ordered_qty  | ROW_NUMBER |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| ASDA    |           12 |          1 |
| ASDA    |           10 |          2 |
| ASDA    |           15 |          3 |
| TESCO   |           12 |          1 |
| TESCO   |           10 |          2 |
| TESCO   |           15 |          3 |
+---------+--------------+------------+
```

Notice how the `ROW_NUMBER` resets after the ASDA values.

The `ORDER BY...` clause then states how to order the rows within the partiion, in our case we've ordered by ordered_qty descending, which gives the following output:

```
+---------+--------------+------------+
| account | ordered_qty  | ROW_NUMBER |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| ASDA    |           15 |          1 |
| ASDA    |           12 |          2 |
| ASDA    |           10 |          3 |
| TESCO   |           15 |          1 |
| TESCO   |           12 |          2 |
| TESCO   |           10 |          3 |
+---------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: When I run that query, it is giving me an error saying I am missing a right parenthesis in row 3. I do not see where one is missing.

Comment: Try again, I was missing a comma between `account_name` and `ordered_item` in the partition by clause.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. It helps seeing it! I am still getting errors with the code.. 'FROM keyword not where expected'. Ill try doing some research to find the reason behind the error unless you post first.

Comment: My Bad! Im not familiar with Oracle SQL, (I use MSSQL) and apparantly you have to have double quotes instead of square brackets for a column alias!

Comment: You only need to put double-quotes around an alias in Oracle if: you need it to be case sensitive or it contains non-standard characters (eg. spaces or starts with a number). In general, it's best to avoid double-quoting aliases, because it forces you to refer to it in exactly the same way wherever you use it. If you don't doublequote it, the alias works, regardless if you type it in UPPERCASE, lowercase or a MiX oF tHe TWo!

Comment: Thanks for that, I knew what was needed for the question, I just wasn't familiar with some of the syntax!

Comment: I am still getting errors with the from statement. Boneist.. Would you mind correcting the code that KidCode posted. I have done my research and still have no idea what syntax I am doing wrong. 

Again.. Thank you both for all the support. I have learned a lot about row_number and partition today. As well as to_date.

Comment: Okay, I took out the "Row" or "AS ROW" and it got rid of the "from" error. It runs everything in the subquery perfectly, just not the right information output. When adding the "Select * from (.... )data where row = 1, it gives me an error saying "missing expression".  Does anyone know the correct syntax for this code in SQLdeveloper?